# Auth0 authentication not working on two specific devices

Tags: web-applications, azure-web-app-service, auth0

I'm hoping for somebody who can point me in the right direction for an Auth0 authentication flow :)

We have a web app running on Azure (Blazor front-end) that uses Auth0 as the identity provider. Users can login with their Azure AD account. Usually the login flow consists of a few calls to Auth0 (first three on the screenshot) and then a call to one of the application's APIs to fetch some additional info after the authentication.

[Network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z6Bq.png)

Now there are two users who repeated (a few weeks time between the reports) that they can no longer login. On their device, only the two first calls are executed (and succeed). The "userinfo" and "GetUserInfo" don't seem to be executed at all, so authentication fails.

We were looking for a problem within the application, but then we noticed:

- The impacted users can still login on any other device, even on the same internet connection
- Other users can't login on the impacted devices either
- The impacted users cannot login with any browser on their impacted device

In other words... Somehow this issue occurs on two machines, and is not related to the user nor the browser. I'm in the dark here:

- Auth0 doesn't seem to be blocking specific devices;
- I wouldn't say our Azure environment could be blocking the traffic, as the last call to Auth0 isn't executed either
- All computers have very similar configuration (can't guarantee they are 100% identical, but same antivirus (SentinelOne), Windows settings pushed through Intune, ...)

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this behavior on two PCs?

Already

- Ruled out that the issue is specific to the Azure accounts or Auth0 users (they can still login on other devices)
- Ruled out that the issue is specific to the browser (cleared browser data and tried fresh browser installs on the impacted devices)

Hoping that somebody has an idea what could be impacting this authentication flow...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally we noticed that these two computers' **time** was not in sync. Apparently when the computer time deviates too much from the actual time, this can happen. Not sure if this is something in our code or something in Auth0... But maybe this can help somebody else one day :)